Why does Sidney believe Mary is trying to deceive him?
Sidney, a press worker, asks Mary, a secretary, for dinner. Mary teases him
about bribing her, but also criticizes his lack of respect:

Mary: You're so immersed...in a theology of making a fast buck. Not
that I don't sometimes feel that you yearn for something better.
Sidney: Mary, don't try and sell me the Brooklyn Bridge. I happen to
know it belongs to the Dodgers.

Here Sidney is essentially telling Mary not to try and fool him with lofty
ideals or insincere sentiments, as he’s too savvy to fall for it.
Why does Sidney believe Mary is trying to deceive him?
